# Replace All Specific Text With Email Link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do is turn all instances of a specific text `CONTACTUSEMAIL` into an email link. This is what I tried:

```
$('body').each(function(){
var AddEmailLink = $(this).html().replace(/(CONTACTUSEMAIL)/, '<a href="mailto:contact@contact.com">contact@contact.com</a>');
$(this).html(AddEmailLink);
});
```

```js
$('body').each(function(){
var AddEmailLink = $(this).html().replace(/(CONTACTUSEMAIL)/, '<a href="mailto:contact@contact.com">contact@contact.com</a>');
$(this).html(AddEmailLink);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

CONTACTUSEMAIL
```

It works, but not without error. It chrome console says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )" and it also says "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.".

How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't get an error, but you're going to want to add a g flag to your regex https://jsfiddle.net/trex005/qe492bbp/

Answer (score 0):

The errors you mention are not caused by your regex

The `Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated` is caused by by an ajax request that is using `async:false` when it should use `promises` and very likely that same request is receiving and invalid or empty response causing the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

OR, another cause may be that you are replacing the full content of your page body, **if your page body contains any `script` tags**, when you re-append them with the content, jQuery appends the script tag to the document and will cause it to load the script with async:false and trigger this warning

If the second case is true, you'll need to move all of your script tags out of the body or change your logic to not replace the full page body

Also, your regex should be `/CONTACTUSEMAIL/` Those parentheses are creating a *capture group*.....but it's a useless capture group in this case